Maui ios hide keyboard when entry is unfocus
Microsoft.Maui.Handlers.EntryHandler.Mapper.AppendToMapping("Borderless", (handler, view) =>
        {
            if (view is ComponentEntry)
            {
#if ANDROID

                handler.PlatformView.Background = null;
                handler.PlatformView.SetBackgroundColor(Android.Graphics.Color.Transparent);
                handler.PlatformView.FocusChange += (object sender, Android.Views.View.FocusChangeEventArgs e) => {
                    if (!e.HasFocus)
                    {
                        Android.Views.InputMethods.InputMethodManager imm = (Android.Views.InputMethods.InputMethodManager)global::Android.App.Application.Context.GetSystemService(global::Android.Content.Context.InputMethodService);
                        if (imm != null)
                        {
                            imm.HideSoftInputFromWindow(handler.PlatformView.WindowToken, 0);
                        }
                    }
                };
#endif

#if IOS
                //handler.PlatformView.BackgroundColor = UIKit.UIColor.Clear;
                //handler.PlatformView.Layer.BorderWidth = 0;
                //handler.PlatformView.BorderStyle = UIKit.UITextBorderStyle.None;

                    handler.PlatformView.ShouldReturn = (textField) => {
                        textField.ResignFirstResponder();
                        return true;
                    };
                    handler.PlatformView.EditingDidEnd += (sender, e) => {
                        ((UIKit.UITextField)sender).ResignFirstResponder();
                    };
#endif


            }
        });

I wanna hide device keyboard when entry is unfocus. Where is wrong in this part which is in program.cs? Especially ios part. Please help me. I don't know ios platform settings.

In MAUI's Entry, clicking the entry key on the keyboard or clicking anywhere outside the keyboard will hide the keyboard. What is your specific demand for hide device keyboard when entry is unfocused？

What .NET version do you use? Do you use Entry Unfocus method to make the entry unfocused?
